# How can I override mouseleave event of uibootstrapper for popover or tooltip in angular js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

How can I override mouseleave event of uibootstrapper for popover or tooltip in angular js?

Comment: like you do to any other event

Comment: actually i want to control close functionality of tooltip.

Comment: have you read the tooltip documentation?